# Prime number formula in python works for all numbers except for 55

Tags: numbers, primes

x = 55

```
for n in range(2,x):
    if x % n == 0:
        print 'Not a prime'
        break

    else:
        print 'Prime'
        break
```

This works for all numbers except for 55...

PS. I am new to programming and trying to learn python.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logical problem in your algorithm,

e.g.

x = 55, then for first loop, n = 2. Since 55 % 2 != 0, you get into Prime branch and break the for loop. So you get result of Prime, which is wrong.

The simplest modification is:

```
x = 55

n = 2

while n < x:
    print(n)
    if x % n == 0:
        print ('Not a prime')
        break
    n = n + 1

if n == x:
    print('Prime')
```

`print(n)` could help you to debug. And actually, verify factor up to `sqrt(x)` will be sufficient.